# 'Tezos' wallet addresses generation

Tags: wallets, api

Can someone please give me a step by step noob guide on how to create a number of (say 100) new addresses(public key hashes, starting with something like 'tz') for my tezos wallet?

Comment: Welcome to Tezos Stack Exchange. You may want to have a short read of [How do I ask a good question?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). It might be a good idea to share what you have tried so far --- as there are a lot of methods to go about doing what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote simple html with JS script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <script src="eztz.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Wallets:</h3>
<p id = "text-id"></p>
</body>
<script>

  let text = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // loop (repeat 10 times)
    let mnemonic = eztz.crypto.generateMnemonic(); // generate mnemonic phrase
    let password = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15); // generate password
    let wallet = eztz.crypto.generateKeys(mnemonic, password); // create wallet by password and mnemonic

    // text with wallet info
    text += "<br><b>Mnemonic:</b> " + mnemonic +
      "<br><b>Password:</b> " + password +
      "<br><b>Public key: </b>" + wallet.pkh +
      "<br><b>Private key: </b>" + wallet.sk + "</br>";
  }

  document.getElementById('text-id').innerHTML = text; // put list of keys to html
</script>
</html>
```

You have to make some simple steps:

1. Download eztz library: https://github.com/TezTech/eztz/blob/master/dist/eztz.min.js
2. Create file with **.html** extension, put my code example into this file.
3. Put created **html** file and downloaded **eztz.min.js** file into the same directory.
4. Open created **html** file with any browser.

Finally you have to see page with 10 generated wallets.