# How to Generate Address in tezos via api?

Tags: node, tezos-client, tzscan

i m trying to generate address via API. 
i don't know how to generate address in tezos. should i deploy my own node for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For generating **tz1** address you don't need node. 
Moreover, you don't need internet connection for generating address)
You need only some library such as [eztz](https://github.com/TezTech/eztz), [sotez](https://github.com/AndrewKishino/sotez) or [ConseilJS](https://cryptonomic.github.io/ConseilJS)

You can find address generation example (for eztz) [here](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/1444/583)

Comment: thanks for help i used sotez npm package for address generation.